# Digital Ocean App Platform does not support relative submodules for GitHub

Tags: git, digital-ocean, git-submodules

I already asked [this question](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/app-platform-does-not-support-relative-submodules-for-github) on the Digital Ocean community forum, but didn't get any reply.
So that's why I'm trying here.

I’m trying to create an app using a private GitHub repository that contains several submodules that are also private.
Because they are part of the same project, I’m using relative addressing.
For example:

"../submodule.git" instead of "https://github.com/Mindesk/submodule.git".

However, while building the application, I stumbled upon the following error:

```
=> Cloning submodules
   warning: error cloning submodules: repository not found
```

For now, I’ve hardcoded the full "https://github.com/Mindesk/" prefix, but I’d rather use the relative address (i.e. "../").

Is this a known issue? And is there something I can do in order to support relative addressing?